# Python SQLAlchemy Update Postgres Record

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to update a row on database (the asynchronous way) using the `multiprocessing` module. My code has a simple function `create_member` that insert some data on a table and then create a process that maybe will change this data. The problem is that the session passed to `async_create_member` is closing the database connection, and the next requisition I get psycopg's error:

```
(Interface Error) connection already closed
```

Here's the code:

```
def create_member(self, data):
    member = self.entity(**data)
    self.session.add(member)
    for name in data:
        setattr(member, name, data[name])
    self.session.commit()
    self.session.close()
    if self.index.is_indexable:
        Process(target=self.async_create_member,
            args=(data, self.session)).start()
    return member

def async_create_member(self, data, session):
    ok, data = self.index.create(data)
    if ok:

        datacopy = data.copy()
        data.clear()
        data['document'] = datacopy['document']
        data['dt_idx'] = datacopy['dt_idx']
        stmt = update(self.entity.__table__).where(
            self.entity.__table__.c.id_doc == datacopy['id_doc'])\
            .values(**data)

        session.begin()
        session.execute(stmt)
        session.commit()
        session.close()
```

I could possibly solve this by creating a new connetion on `async_create_member`, but this was leaving too much `idle` transactions on postgres:

```
engine = create_new_engine()
conn = engine.connect()
conn.execute(stmt)
conn.close()
```

What should I do now? is there a way to solve the first code? Or Should I keep creating new connections with `create_new_engine` function? Should I use threads or processes ?

Comment: I believe if you remove the `self.session.close()` in the create_member function it should work

Comment: Already tried. No success

Comment: Hmm that's odd the only reason you should be getting that exception is because you are closing the connection to the server.  I'm also thinking you don't need the begin() there.  I'm assuming you're getting this error in the session.execute(stmt) line?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't reuse sessions across threads or processes. [Sessions aren't thread safe](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html#is-the-session-thread-safe), and the connectivity that underlies a Session isn't inherited cleanly across processes. The error message you are getting is accurate, if uninformative: the DB connection is indeed closed if you try to use it after inheriting it across a process boundary.

In most cases, yes, you should create a session for each process in a `multiprocessing` setting.

If your problem meets the following conditions:

- you are doing a lot of CPU-intensive processing for each object
- database writes are relatively lightweight in comparison
- you want to use a lot of processes (I do this on 8+ core machines)

It might be worth your while to create a single writer process that owns a session, and pass the objects to that process. Here's how it usually works for me (Note: not meant to be runnable code):

```
import multiprocessing
from your_database_layer import create_new_session, WhateverType

work = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()

def writer(commit_every = 50):
    global work
    session = create_new_session()
    counter = 0

    while True:
        item = work.get()
        if item is None:
            break

        session.add(item)
        counter += 1
        if counter % commit_every == 0:
            session.commit()

        work.task_done()

    # Last DB writes
    session.commit()

    # Mark the final None in the queue as complete
    work.task_done()
    return


def very_expensive_object_creation(data):
    global work
    very_expensive_object = WhateverType(**data)
    # Perform lots of computation
    work.put(very_expensive_object)
    return


def main():
    writer_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=writer)
    writer_process.start()

    # Create your pool that will feed the queue here, i.e.
    workers = multiprocessing.Pool()
    # Dispatch lots of work to very_expensive_object_creation in parallel here
    workers.map(very_expensive_object_creation, some_iterable_source_here)
    # --or-- in whatever other way floats your boat, such as
    workers.apply_async(very_expensive_object_creation, args=(some_data_1,))
    workers.apply_async(very_expensive_object_creation, args=(some_data_2,))
    # etc.

    # Signal that we won't dispatch any more work
    workers.close()

    # Wait for the creation work to be done
    workers.join()

    # Trigger the exit condition for the writer
    work.put(None)

    # Wait for the queue to be emptied
    work.join()

    return
```

Comment: having a worker public variable and module level can lead to memory leak and that you are using it to mark `task_done()` can stuck the query. I dont know how that is an acceptable answer